# Creating dynamically named gui objects in Python with tkinter

Tags: python, button, methods, tkinter

I'm learning to use tkinter in Python 3.6.4.  I am creating a GUI with multiple instances of buttons.  Two such instances are:

```
def createWidgets(self):
    # first button
    self.QUIT = Button(self)
    self.QUIT["text"] = "Quit"
    self.QUIT["command"] = self.quit
    self.QUIT.pack()

    # second button
    self.Reset  = Button(self)
    self.Reset["text"] = "Reset"
    self.Reset["command"] = "some other function, tbd"
```

What I want to learn is how to abstract the instantiation of buttons such that each instance in the createWidgets method is based on a method something like this:

```
createButton( self, text, command, fg, bg, hgt, wth, cursor ):
```

What I don't know is how to control the naming of the button as:

```
self.QUIT
self.Reset
```

where the property or name following the "." operator can be passed to the createButton as a property by which the button is created and named.

Comment: use a dictionary. `self.widget["QUIT"]`

Comment: Something like this?  def createButton( self, text):, followed by self.widget( text ) = Button( self), where text can be "QUIT" or other string?

Comment: It that is correct, then in the main method, createWidgets, the use of createButton is used how, please?

Comment: Benjamin, I noticed you have not accepted any answer for any of the question you have asked. Please take the time to select the check box next to the answer that helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply expanding on what Brian said, this code will get you going. The button objects are stored in a widget dictionary. Here is one way to put this together:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

root = tk.Tk()

class CustomButton(tk.Button):

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, parent)
        for attribute,value in kwargs.items():
            try:
                self[attribute] = value
            except:
                raise

def doReset():
    print("doRest not yet implemented")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    widget = {}
    widget['quit'] = CustomButton(root, text='Quit', command=sys.exit)
    widget['reset'] = CustomButton(root, text='Reset', command=doReset)
    for button in widget.keys():
        widget[button].pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Got it.  Much obliged.

Comment: @BenjaminLevy You can select a single answer if it was the most helpful one to you.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: @BenjaminLevy I'm not sure what you mean by _"this"_ but there's upvote and there's answer select, the answer above isn't selected, but it was upvoted as of now 3 times.

Comment: Sorry, Nae.  Forgot to click on the 'check' icon.